# Detect same images name {iPhone SDK}

Tags: iphone

i want create image animation , i have 50 images with png format now i want set images name ... something like this but doesnt work !

my images name are : `iamge_0000 to image_0050`

```
pasheAnimation.animationImages  = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"pashe_0000.png"],nil];

    [pasheAnimation setAnimationRepeatCount:5];
    pasheAnimation.animationDuration = 4;
    [pasheAnimation startAnimating];
```

??!?!?!?

jason Code [EDITED] :

```
NSMutableArray* myImages = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:607] autorelease];
    for( int i = 1; i <= 607; i++ ) {
        [myImages addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"p%d.png",i]]];
    }

    butterflyView.animationImages = myImages;
    [butterflyView setAnimationRepeatCount:100];
    butterflyView.animationDuration = 0;
    [butterflyView startAnimating];
```

Comment: You have to change the string format to actually represent your image name. So, if your image is named pashe_0000.png your string format needs to be pashe_%04d.png -- that is very important. Also, do you really have 608 images?

Comment: Jason , i changed my file names and changed them to p1 to p607
 my app crash again ..  that drive me crazy !!!! :@
yeah it's short animation PLZ help me

Comment: i edit my code again.  take a look

Comment: So the actual image name is something like p1.png?

Comment: that drive me crazy plz survive me ! here is my sample code plz take look i really need solve this problem :

download : [396 KB]
http://www.multiupload.com/PK3Z4FYHJU

Comment: @Morneks: The code you posted at this link works fine for me. Where exactly does this crash and what error do you get? One thing you might try is clean-all and rebuild. Are you sure you are using the latest compiled version and not an old version of the app?

Comment: YEs .. finally works for me good ... but works great on simulator ! when install my app on the device seems running out of memory. !
it's new problem :))
whats the solution ? should i work with memory management ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// There are actually 51 images in this series (0000-0050)     
NSMutableArray* myImages = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:51] autorelease];
for( int i = 0; i <= 50; i++ ) {
  [myImages addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"image_%04d.png", i]]?:[NSNull null]];
}
```

Comment: -1: If the UIImage is nil this will throw an exception. Also, it should be %04, not %02, for a four-character length zero-padded decimal.

Comment: @Alex Reynolds: I don't really know what your problem is with me, but I didn't vote you down, even though your answer was misleading.

Comment: @Alex Reynolds: It was a reference answer to his question, so I didn't do the error checking. Your answer simply silently ignores missing images. I'd argue that my answer would actually be better since it would be obvious that there is a programming error (missing images in the series), but it's updated anyway.

Comment: Further, unless `myImages` gets a `release` somewhere, this will create a memory leak.

Comment: Yes, he owns myImages. He will have to release them. This is a code snippet, not even a full function.

Comment: It's misleading not to include the `release` message, since the OP is using the autoreleased `-arrayWithObjects:` method.

Comment: @Jongsma: What? If this chunk of code is used as-is, it will introduce a memory leak. Is that incorrect?

Comment: No, Alex, it wouldn't. There is no context around this chunk of code, there is no closing scope so there is no memory leak. myImages is owned by whatever scope encloses it, and the regular memory management rules apply (meaning that it would have to be released or assigned to a variable with a larger scope). I added an autorelease just for you tho ;)

Comment: Thank  you everybody ... iam a little bit amateur .i edited my post and write whole the animation code can you edit your code relate my animation code ? thank you

Comment: Jason i edit my post according your code ! but doesn't work and crash !

Answer (score 1):

You actually have 51 images, from zero to fifty.

```
NSMutableArray *myImages = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:51];
for (NSUInteger idx = 0; idx <= 50; idx++) {
    NSString *filename = [NSString stringWithFormat:"image_%04d.png", idx];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:filename];
    if (image) {
        [myImages addObject:image];
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Could not add %@", filename); // could also throw exception, if you want
    }
}
```